# Plotting squares, triangles and circles when using smooth bezier with gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am usually using `smooth bezier` when plotting my data. It makes then easier to understand and also nicer to see. However, I would also like to plot circles, triangles and squares in the right place i.e. where I've got real data. How could I do that?

I'll give an example of what I do:

```
p "times" u 1:2 w lp smooth bezier title "Time 1", "" u 1:3 w lp smooth bezier title "Time 2"
set xtics("0" 0,"1" 1, "2" 2,"4" 4 ,"8" 8)
```

getting:
[image]

Now I want to set triangles in the green line to the right point corresponding to x=1, x=2,x=4 and x=8. Same for the red line, but instead triangles, circles, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just plot the data again without smoothing:

```
CIRCLEPT = 6
TRIANGLEPT = 9
set xtics("0" 0,"1" 1, "2" 2,"4" 4 ,"8" 8)
plot "times" u 1:2 w lp lt 1 smooth bezier title "Time 1", \
     "" u 1:2 w p lt 1 pt CIRCLEPT notitle , \
     "" u 1:3 w lp lt 2 smooth bezier title "Time 2", \
     "" u 1:3 w p lt 2 pt TRIANGLEPT notitle
```

As far as getting triangles and circles, you'll need to select the proper point type for your terminal.  To figure out which point type to use, you'll need to do something like:

```
set terminal <whatever>
set output <whatever>  #only for non-interactive terminals
test
```

Now you can look at whatever output was generated by `test` and along the right side will be a bunch of points of different types.  Just pick the type you want (e.g. 7 is often a circle) and put it in the script